# Como resolver mensagem de erro gerada pela função GetSQLValueString

Tags: php

Estou usando a função `GetSQLValueString`do `dreamweaver`para fazer a validação de algumas variáveis e tudo funciona bem, mas fazendo um teste com o programa `Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner 9.5` me deparei com uma mensagem de erro fornecida por ele, acusando uma possível brecha de segurança.
A url gerada pelo programa e a mensagem é essa:

> http://meusite.com.br/cidades.ajax.php?ajax=true&search=&uf[]=27
>
> PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be
>   string, array given in E:\home\topdeia\Web\n-chipi\cidades.ajax.php on
>   line 22

A função é essa:

```
    if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {

function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);     

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
```

A pergunta é, tem como contornar esse erro?

Comment: Sempre é uma uf apenas?

Comment: Olá @rray, sim, sempre será uma UF por vez, nesse caso a UF está sendo invocada ao clicar em uma área de um mapa para exibição de representantes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AVISO:** As funções `mysql_*`  não deve ser usadas.

O problema é que a função espera um valor escalar porém um array foi passado como argumento, quem dá a dica é a query string (`&uf[]=27`).

Primeiro precisa decidir se vier um array vai abortar o processo e retornar uma mensagem de erro ao usuário ou pegar o primeiro elemento do array e usar?

Para o segundo caso como apenas uma uf deve ser enviado por vez pode utilizar a função `reset()` para por o ponteiro do array na primeira posição e pegar seu valor.

```
$theValue = is_array($theValue) ? reset($theValue) :  $theValue; //linha adicionada

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela grande ajuda @rray, problema resolvido.